# How can I serialize and deserialize components in Vaadin Flow 14?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

Let's say that I have a bunch of text fields, text boxes, buttons with names on and check boxes etc.

When I press the save button, I want to save all these components. I wrote a class that will pick out the intrested value from these components. But the problem is, that it will become to much code for this.

It must be a simplier way to just save data from the components into a file?

Comment: What vaadion version?  In V8 there is writeDesign

Comment: @cfrick It's vaadin 14

Comment: I don't think "serialization" is the proper technical term for what you want. Are you asking about persisting data values from the user's inputs to storage? Are you using a database? See "serialization" versus "persistence" in Wikipedia.

Comment: @BasilBourque I think serialization will work fine for me. I will thest the answer today and then give a reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your data is represented as business objects (JavaBeans), then it's easier to achieve your aim using Vaadin's Binder class (which has other side-benefits such as facilitating components' validation and conversion). In it's simplest form, it could look something like this:

```
Binder<Person> binder = new Binder<>(Person.class);
TextField text= new TextField();
binder.bind(text, Person::getName, Person::setName);

Person person = new Person("First Last");
//Then you can set this person bean to be automatically in sync
//with the the TextField like so
binder.setBean(person);
```

Vaadin's documentation has many more examples and advanced use cases:
https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/binding-data/tutorial-flow-components-binder.html

Comment: Looks great! But then I save the binder object to a file and then I can load it as well?

Comment: Not the binder object, you'd save your bean (or beans) and load it again

Comment: How do I save the bean? I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson no you don't save the binder object, but the bean that is set in the binder. In this case, you can see the binder as a helper to get to your bean that is represented by all bound input fields. the serialization and deserialization of the bean can then be done with an [objectmapper](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial)

Comment: @kscherrer Not sure how to save or load the bean.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson You'd save and load it like you'd do with any java object. For further help on how to do that, check for example: https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-write-java-object-to-a-file/

Comment: @TarekOraby thanks, I know how to save classes with the "implements serializable". So I should not save the binder object...so which object should I save? What bean are you talking about? Bean is the object in a container?

Comment: In the above example, the bean is the person object.

Comment: @TarekOraby My data is represented by Vaadin classes.

Comment: I will try that tomorrow and give an answer.